# Как составить SQL-запрос с двойным условием?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица с подобным содержимым:

[image]

Необходимо составить SQL-запрос, чтобы получить имена, которые получили одновременно по математике и русскому языку 5 баллов. То есть в нашем случаи это только Иван.

Comment: я несильно разбираюсь в SQL, но имхо нельзя составлять таблицу ТАК. нужно ввести две таблицы (предмет+ученик) и foreign key

Comment: @argamidon это учебное задание

Comment: Нет - это не учебное задание. Я просто упростил, чтобы было нагляднее. Я делаю анализ результатов ЕГЭ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, если имена не повторяются, то можно так:

```
SELECT a.name FROM table1 a JOIN table1 b ON a.name = b.name WHERE a.subject = 'Русский язык' AND b.subject = 'Математика' AND a.grade = 5 AND b.grade = 5;
```

Comment: а если еще будет столбец Фамилия?

Answer (score 4):

Я бы воспользовался [INTERSECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188055.aspx)

```
SELECT
    Имя
FROM
    table1
WHERE
    Предмет = 'Математика'
    AND Балл = 5
INTERSECT
SELECT
    Имя
FROM
    table1
WHERE
    Предмет = 'Русский язык'
    AND Балл = 5;
```

> а если еще будет столбец Фамилия?

Чтобы было все-равно на количество информации о студенте, у Вас должно быть для каждой сущности своя таблица. Заведите таблицу студентов

| id | first_name | last_name | ....

И из таблицы результатов ссылайтесь на нее внешним ключом. Получится как-то так:

| Предмет | student_id | Балл |

(Кстати, список предметов надо бы тоже хранить как отдельную таблицу-справочник)

Тогда запрос получится таким:

```
SELECT
    S.first_name -- имя
    ,S.last_name -- фамилия
    ,... Любые другие поля из students
FROM
(
    SELECT
        student_id
    FROM
        table1
    WHERE
        Предмет = 'Математика'
        AND Балл = 5
    INTERSECT
    SELECT
        student_id
    FROM
        table1
    WHERE
        Предмет = 'Русский язык'
        AND Балл = 5
) X
INNER JOIN
    students S ON S.id = X.student_id;
```

Почитайте про нормальные формы БД

Answer (score 2):

```
select name
from tab
where subject in ("РЯ","Мат")
  and mark=5
group by name
having count(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Имя
FROM Таблица
WHERE предмет = Математика AND
балл = 5 AND Имя
IN (SELECT Имя 
FROM Таблица
WHERE предмет = Русский язык AND
балл = 5)
```