# Как составить запрос с выводом разницы двух множеств с условием WHERE?

Tags: php, sql

Есть 2 таблицы:

admin_files:

```
id  |  signature
 1   |        1
 2   |        1
 3   |        1
```

support_files:

```
id  |  support_id  |  admin_file_id
 1   |        2           |        1  
 2   |        2           |        2 
 3   |        2           |        3

function signature($id){
global $connection;
$query = "SELECT a.* FROM admin_files a LEFT JOIN support_files s ON s.admin_file_id = a.id WHERE s.admin_file_id IS NULL";
$res = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $signature = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $signature[$row['id']] = $row;
    }
    return $signature;
```

}

Выводит разницу, но не работает, если добавить условие в

```
WHERE s.admin_file_id IS NULL AND a.signature= 1 AND s.support_id='$id'";
```

Условия `a.signature= 1 AND s.support_id='$id'` нужны обязательно, куда можно их пристроить?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT a.* FROM admin_files a LEFT JOIN support_files s ON s.admin_file_id = a.id AND s.support_id='$id' WHERE s.admin_file_id IS NULL AND a.signature= 1";
```

всё, сделал, так работает как надо

Answer (score 0):

Для этого есть оператор MINUS. Операция, обратная UNION.

Comment: этого не достаточно для ответа. предложите решение вопроса

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-minus/

Comment: этот сайт - база знаний, а не база счылок. нормальный ответ выглядит так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/383497/2659